# Converting nested array to object, matching array index with object id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

i'm currently struggling with a redux reducer.

```js
//backend response
const response = {
    data: {
        results: {
            222: {
                items: ['id1', 'id3']
            },
            333: {
                items: ['id2', 'id4', 'id999 (UNKNOWN)']
            }
        }
    }
};

//currently saved in redux state
const stateItems = [
    {
        id: 'id1',
        name: 'item ONE'
    }, {
        id: 'id2',
        name: 'item TWO'
    }, {
        id: 'id3',
        name: 'item THREE'
    }, {
        id: 'id4',
        name: 'item FOUR'
    }, {
        id: 'id5',
        name: 'item FIVE (UNUSED)'
    }, {
        id: 'id6',
        name: 'item SIX (UNUSED)'
    }
];


//converting items: ['ids'] => items: [{id: 'id', name: 'itemName'}]
const result = Object.values(response.data.results).map((keys, index, array) => {
    keys.items = keys.items.map(itemId => {
        return stateItems[stateItems.findIndex(x => x.id === itemId)];
    });

    return response.data.results;
});


//final result should be:
const expectedFinalResult = {
    222: {items: [{id: 'id1', name: 'item ONE'}, {id: 'id3', name: 'item THREE'}]},
    333: {items: [{id: 'id2', name: 'item TWO'}, {id: 'id4', name: 'item FOUR'}]}
};

//both should be equal:
console.log(JSON.stringify(expectedFinalResult));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log('same result: ' + JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expectedFinalResult));
```

I ran out of ideas, how to realize it. `UNUSED` and `UNKNOWN` should be filtered out as well. So that the final result in this example just be like in the `const expectedFinalResult`. Currently the `const result` return a wrong result back.

Hopefully someone have an better idea oder better approach.

Thank you

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets for runnable examples rather than off-site resources. You open the Snippet editor using the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Since you'd included all of the relevant code in the question (nice!) I've copied it into a snippet for you.

Comment: Note: `JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expectedFinalResult)` is ***not*** a reliable way to compare two object graphs. `JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) === JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1})` is `false`, for instance (per spec).

Comment: Great job showing your effort in the question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `Object.entries`. You can use destructuring to pick out the key (`'222'`, `'333'`) and the value object's `items` array, then use that array to filter `stateItems` and produce the `items` array for each entry in the result:

```
const result = {};
for (const [key, {items}] of Object.entries(response.data.results)) {
    result[key] = {
        items: stateItems.filter(item => items.includes(item.id))
    };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
//backend response
const response = {
    data: {
        results: {
            222: {
                items: ['id1', 'id3']
            },
            333: {
                items: ['id2', 'id4', 'id999 (UNKNOWN)']
            }
        }
    }
};

//currently saved in redux state
const stateItems = [
    {
        id: 'id1',
        name: 'item ONE'
    }, {
        id: 'id2',
        name: 'item TWO'
    }, {
        id: 'id3',
        name: 'item THREE'
    }, {
        id: 'id4',
        name: 'item FOUR'
    }, {
        id: 'id5',
        name: 'item FIVE (UNUSED)'
    }, {
        id: 'id6',
        name: 'item SIX (UNUSED)'
    }
];


const result = {};
for (const [key, {items}] of Object.entries(response.data.results)) {
    result[key] = {
        items: stateItems.filter(item => items.includes(item.id))
    };
}

//final result should be:
const expectedFinalResult = {
    222: {items: [{id: 'id1', name: 'item ONE'}, {id: 'id3', name: 'item THREE'}]},
    333: {items: [{id: 'id2', name: 'item TWO'}, {id: 'id4', name: 'item FOUR'}]}
};

//both should be equal:
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That makes multiple passes through `stateItems`. If it or `response.data.results` is really, really, really, really big (like hundreds of thousands), it may be worthwhile to do a `Map` of the `stateItem`s by `id` instead:

```
// Create map of state items (only once each time stateItems changes):
const stateItemMap = new Map(stateItems.map(item => [item.id, item]));

// Map results (each time you get results):
const result = {};
for (const [key, {items}] of Object.entries(response.data.results)) {
    result[key] = {
        items: items.map(id => stateItemMap.get(id))
    };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
//backend response
const response = {
    data: {
        results: {
            222: {
                items: ['id1', 'id3']
            },
            333: {
                items: ['id2', 'id4', 'id999 (UNKNOWN)']
            }
        }
    }
};

//currently saved in redux state
const stateItems = [
    {
        id: 'id1',
        name: 'item ONE'
    }, {
        id: 'id2',
        name: 'item TWO'
    }, {
        id: 'id3',
        name: 'item THREE'
    }, {
        id: 'id4',
        name: 'item FOUR'
    }, {
        id: 'id5',
        name: 'item FIVE (UNUSED)'
    }, {
        id: 'id6',
        name: 'item SIX (UNUSED)'
    }
];

// Create map of state items (only once each time stateItems changes):
const stateItemMap = new Map(stateItems.map(item => [item.id, item]));

// Map results (each time you get results):
const result = {};
for (const [key, {items}] of Object.entries(response.data.results)) {
    result[key] = {
        items: items.map(id => stateItemMap.get(id))
    };
}

//final result should be:
const expectedFinalResult = {
    222: {items: [{id: 'id1', name: 'item ONE'}, {id: 'id3', name: 'item THREE'}]},
    333: {items: [{id: 'id2', name: 'item TWO'}, {id: 'id4', name: 'item FOUR'}]}
};

//both should be equal:
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks and thanks for the previous tipps. I tried it before with `.entries`, but i thought it's the wrong direction, i didn't tried with the for loop. The arrays won't be big.. Mostly 1-100 items.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with reduce:

```
Object.entries(response.data.results)
    .reduce((acc, [key, { items }]) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: { // we can use the dynamic keys to add in our accumulated object
            items: items
                .map(itemId => stateItems.find(x => x.id === itemId)) // you can use find directly instead of findIndex then access
                .filter(Boolean) // we skip the unneeded elements
        }
    }), {});
```